# Pass array items to table view cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array that I'm looping through and passing the value to my table view cell label. But when i pass the values ,the label only shows the last value of the array. I want it to show the whole items coming from an array. How I can show that?

```
let addonDescrip = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].addonDescp
print(addonDescrip)
for items in addonDescrip{
    print(items)
    cell.descriptionLbl.text = items
    print(cell.descriptionLbl.text)
}
```

I want it to show items in this sequence:

```
item1,
item2,
item4
```

How can we show like this in table view cell label?
My table view delegates,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell

    cell.dishTitleLbl.text = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].itemName!
    cell.priceLbl.text = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].totalPrice!
    print(cell.priceLbl.text!)

        let addonDescrip = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].addonDescp
        print(addonDescrip)
        for items in addonDescrip{
            print(items)
            cell.descriptionLbl.text = items
            print(cell.descriptionLbl.text)
        }

    cell.quantityLbl.text = "1"//String(ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].cartItem)
    itemname = cell.dishTitleLbl.text!
    itemDescription = cell.descriptionLbl.text!
    itemprice = cell.priceLbl.text!
    itemID = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].itemID!
    cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.minusBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.quantityLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    cell.quantityLbl.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)
    cell.quantityLbl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all items in one label then append the string like this

```
    for (index,item) in addonDescrip.enumerated() {
        print(items)
        if index == 0 {
           cell.descriptionLbl.text = item
        } else {
           cell.descriptionLbl.text = cell.descriptionLbl.text + "," + item
        }

        print(cell.descriptionLbl.text)
    }
```

**OR**

```
   cell.descriptionLbl.text = addonDescrip.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: this array is coming from my model class and it contains multiple items and this item is to be passed to the cell label and i think for loop would be run on it. @RajeshKumar R

Comment: If the array contains 5 objects you'll need to create 5 cells. Each cell will have one label. What are you returning in numberofrows method?

Comment: this is not that array which i want to show on table view whole its only passing its data to one label in a cell there are other labels also in a cell. @RajeshKumar R

Comment: let me try. @RajeshKumar R

Comment: @raheem I've updated answer to append comma for all items except first one

Comment: yup got it now that what i want, thanks a lot. @RajeshKumar R